# SwiftUI - Perform action when cancel is clicked - .searchable function

Tags: search, swiftui, ios15

When using the `.searchable(text: $text)` function, a cancel button appears in the search bar when searching.

Is there any way to perform an action when the cancel button is clicked? I would like to call a function when cancel is clicked, but cannot figure out how to perform an action when cancel is tapped.

The [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/searchable(text:placement:)) does not mention anything about this. Back in UIKit there was the `func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {` to do this.

Below is an image of the cancel button I am referring to:[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `isSearching` environment value (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/issearching?changes=_6) to see if a search is being performed. To do an action upon cancelation, you could watch for a change from `true` to `false` using `onChange`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @Environment(\.dismissSearch) var dismissSearch
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ChildView()
                Text("Searching for \(searchText)")
                
            }
            
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
            .navigationTitle("Searchable Example")
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView : View {
    @Environment(\.isSearching) var isSearching
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Child")
            .onChange(of: isSearching) { newValue in
                if !newValue {
                    print("Searching cancelled")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

*Probably important to note that it seems like `isSearching` has to be inside a child view of the `searchable` modifier in order for it to work properly*

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the documentation. Wouldn't it change to false if the user clicked the "Search" button as well?

Comment: Not in my testing, no. Are you experiencing something different?

Comment: Just wanted to pick your brain before implementing. Tested and working as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Based on @jnpdx 's answer, something equivalent, but more generic is:

```
struct SearchView<Content: View>: View {
    @Environment(\.isSearching) var isSearching
    let content: (Bool) -> Content

    var body: some View {
        content(isSearching)
    }

    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Bool) -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
}
```

And then, use it like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @Environment(\.dismissSearch) var dismissSearch
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                SearchView { isSearching in
                    Text("Child")
                        .onChange(of: isSearching) { newValue in
                            if !newValue {
                                print("Searching cancelled")
                            }
                        }
                }
                Text("Searching for \(searchText)")
                
            }
            
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
            .navigationTitle("Searchable Example")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very good solution to avoid creating unnecessary subviewing.

Answer (score 2):

use `isEmpty` and `onAppear`.

```swift
struct SearchView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if text.isEmpty {
                    main.onAppear {
                        print("empty")
                        // code here
                    }
                } else {
                    main
                }
            }.searchable(text: $text)
                .onSubmit(of: .search) {
                    print("submit")
                }
        }
    }
    
    var main: some View {
        Text("search").searchable(text: $text)
    }
}
```

Comment: This can cause major performance issues on large lists.